# Why did my bounty disappear?

Tags: support, bounty

This isn't a case of the bounty getting auto-awarded at the end of the grace period. I created a 50-point bounty for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52942232/creating-vignette-from-md-file-not-rmd) yesterday. Today, I see that the bounty is gone, and I've been refunded the 50 rep points.

I actually got an answer that solved the problem, and I was going to award the bounty once the expiry was up (unless someone else posts a better answer, of course). How can I get the bounty back?

Comment: Refunding a bounty would be the work of a moderator. There must have been a reason; usually, this goes with closing the question, so I'm not sure.

Comment: Oh that's weird... they deleted it and then restored it a minute later.

Comment: @StephenLeppik Restored it? What do you mean? And where are you seeing this?

Comment: I checked the timeline. By "restored", I mean they undeleted it.

Comment: Maybe they meant to delete a different question with a bounty and it was just a mistake. Do you have any messages from Stack Overflow in your email?

Comment: @StephenLeppik You can see the timeline for the question? I don't see such a link; as far as I can tell, there haven't been any edits.

Comment: @BSMP no email. It may have been eaten by my spam filter though.

Comment: The timeline is on any post as `/posts/{{id}}/timeline`.

Comment: Oh wow, you learn something new every day

Comment: We going to ignore the fact this is a poor question and should have at least been put on hold anyway until the OP provided some more detailed information?

Comment: @Lankymart: Nothing wrong with pointing it out, only it's a separate issue from the one at hand.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

**This was my fault. I'm sorry.**

I was handling a bunch of flags, and your question was in the list because it had received "close vote flags" (flags cast by users who think the question should be closed but who do not have the close-vote privilege). While I was scrolling down the page, I accidentally hit the "delete question" button, one of the default buttons moderators can see when reviewing flags on questions.

As soon as I realized my mistake, I undeleted the post. Unfortunately, deleting it had the effect of refunding your bounty. **Please feel free to add the bounty again.**

Once again, I'm sorry about that.

Comment: When something like this happens do Mods notify impacted users by e-mail or some other means?

Comment: @PM77-1 Not usually, no, because there are usually no side effects to tell anyone about. It would be strange to send an email that says, “Hey, your question was offline for 37 seconds,” or whatever; it’s highly unlikely anyone was affected. In this case, there *were* side effects, but I honestly didn’t realize that until this Meta post went up. The bounty wasn’t visible in the mod tools, so I didn’t know there was one. (Also, FWIW, in the past, deleting the question wouldn’t have refunded the bounty.) If I had realized that a bounty was affected, I would have sent a message before it hit Meta.

Comment: I reported multiple open-bounty-should-be-closed questions. I think you people should treat close vote flags, from people who have cv privilege and people who don't have cv privilege, separately. People who have cv privilege will raise a custom mod flag only if the question have an open bounty or it is a locked one.

Comment: @SagarV We do treat them separately. That’s why this question was in the moderation queue.